# AngularJS - ui-mask apply to span

Tags: angularjs

I want to apply ui-mask to a `span`. I have this directive imported.

When i use `ui-mask` in `input` html, it works properly.

How to apply `ui-mask` to a `span`?

Comment: How you intend to use it in a `span`? The intended use case of ui-mask goes with using it in an `input` element along with an `ng-model`